# Solving the continued fraction functional equation $f(x) = g(x) + \frac1{f(x^n)}$.

Tags: functional-equations, continued-fractions

I am wondering what non-constant functions satisfy the functional equation:

> $$f(x) = g(x) + \frac1{f(x^n)}$$

For some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ on a domain for which $f(x^{nk}) \neq 0$. For the $n=1$ case, we have
$$f(x)^2-f(x)g(x)-1=0 \implies f(x) =\frac{g(x)\pm \sqrt{g(x)^2+4}}{2}$$
So we may choose just about any $g(x)$ and find a satisfactory $f(x)$. But I am unsure how to find solutions for $n>1$. How might I begin? Are there any known examples?

Additional question, need not be answered: are there any examples of *compositions of elementary functions* satisfying the highlighted equation, not of the form $x^a+b$?

Comment: The equation you derived always holds for $x=0,1$. The equation is also true for $x=-1$ when $n$ is odd. I'm not really sure if this is of much help.

Comment: When $n$ is even we have that $f(-x) - g(-x) = f(x) - g(x)$, or $f(x) - f(-x) = g(x) - g(-x)$. In other words, $f$ and $g$ have the same odd part.

Comment: The equation seems a bit disjointed to me actually. For $n>1$, we can consider the family of orbits $\left\{x^{n^k}\,|\, x\in\Bbb R, \, k\in\Bbb N\right\}$.
When $n$ is odd, we don't need to worry about signs, and any two orbits that intersect are such that one is contained in another. We may then consider maximal orbits as the union of these chains.

If one prescribes a value for $f$ along the elements of a given orbit, then $g$ is also prescribed along these values via the functional equation. *(continues)*

Comment: *(continued)* Conversely, if one prescribes a value for $g$ along the elements of a given orbit and also the value of $f$ on a single element of the given orbit, then all other values of $f$ along that orbit are also prescribed via the functional equation.

So there seems to be a lot of freedom with what we can do here in building patchy $f$s and $g$s that work.